# True\False: does the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ imply that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cdot \sin n$ converges absolutely?

Tags: calculus

I have this question:

True\False:
does the convergence of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n$ imply that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cdot \sin n$ converge absolutely?

I think this is not true, I tried using something like $a_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}$ and using variations with things like $\cos (n)^{n+1}$ to get opposite values but I failed.

Comment: Obviously false. The second series does not involve $a_n$

Comment: Do you mean $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \sin \color{red}{a_n}$?

Comment: @Eff yes sorry fixed! thank you

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen fixed that sorry!

Comment: Still false, take $a_n=\frac{\sin{n}}{n}$.

Answer (score 1):

False.  Consider an increasing  sequence $m_k$ of integers such that $\sin(m_k) > 1/2$ if $k$ is odd and $\sin(m_k) < -1/2$ if $k$ is even.  Take $a_{m_k} = (-1)^k/k$, $a_n = 0$ otherwise.

Comment: This isn't easy to find, I see why this took me so much effort, thank you